# ¿Cómo escribo el subjuntivo presente de 'adelgazar'?

Tags: verbos, ortografía, subjuntivo, conjugación, deletreo

Según el sitio [conjugation.org](http://conjugation.org/cgi-bin/conj.php), el subjuntivo presente del verbo *adelgazar* es:

> yo adelgaze
>   tú adelgazes
>   él/usted adelgaze
>   nosotros adelgazemos
>   vosotros adelgazéis
>   ellos/ustedes adelgazen

Pero, creí que cuando una *e* sigue una *z*, la *z* tiene que cambiar a *c*.  Entonces, creo que conjugation.org tiene un error.  ¿Sí o no?

Entonces, creo que las formas correctas son:

> yo adelgace
>   tú adelgaces
>   él/usted adelgace
>   nosotros adelgacemos
>   vosotros adelgacéis
>   ellos/ustedes adelgacen

(Y mi corrector ortográfico cree eso también.)

Comment: El sitio [Verbix](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/Spanish/adelgazar.html) tiene las formas tuyas.

Comment: es un error sin duda. La conjugación correcta de este tiempo es con "c".

Comment: Sugiero usar mejor la referencia oficial (RAE), ya que probablemente tenga menos errores ya que es revisado a fondo continuamente. Hay un botón llamado "Conjugar" al buscar un verbo que te muestra todas las tablas. http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=adelgazar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como comenta Javi, es un error de la aplicación. Puedes checar en la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/adelgazar) que las formas correctas son:

- yo adelgace
- tú adelgaces
- él adelgace
- nosotros adelgacemos
- vosotros/ustedes adelgacéis / adelgacen
- ellos adelgacen